# Trying to replicate duplicate effect

Tags: html, css

Hello I was recently browsing around some demo for websites for client. And saw a really cool thing I liked. So I try to inspect in the browser to see if I replicate the effect on my own. And I have no idea how they did it.

here is the link to the demo
http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/45057.html
And here is a n image to show what I'm talking about.

They have these squares with an overflow at the bottom looking like multiple elements.

I was able to grab the HTML/CSS and replicate the just one box without the overflow. But I can't figure out how to make it look like stacked boxes, nor can I find where the code is.

I tried to replicate using JSFidle as you can see here
HTML

```
<div class="span2"><div class="service-box boxed green"><a href="coding/mauris-posuere/"><figure class="icon"><i class="icon-file-alt"></i></figure><div class="service-box_body"><h2 class="title">Accounting valuations</h2></div></a></div> </div>

.service-box.boxed {
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 25px 15px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #F1F6F9;
    overflow: visible;
    border: 1px solid #C5D0D2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w1defmkz/
[image]

Comment: There is a `:before` and `:after` pseudo element. That's where the magic happens.

Comment: Appreciate it. Somehow I missed it and feel silly. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're pretty close but missing the [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) and [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo elements:

```
.service-box.boxed:before, .service-box.boxed:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  bottom: -4px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #f1f6f9;
  border: 1px solid #c5d0d2;
  border-top: none;
}

.service-box.boxed:before, .service-box.boxed:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  bottom: -4px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #f1f6f9;
  border: 1px solid #c5d0d2;
  border-top: none;
}

.service-box.boxed:after {
  left: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  bottom: -7px;
}
```

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w1defmkz/1/

Comment: I actually solved it from the tip in the comments before I saw your answer. I feel silly now but thank you.

Comment: @WebDev - Glad you got it sorted. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Well, The user has added two more divisions, made them absolute.

You see, the whole span (class = "span2") is positioned relative.

This is the css for the one of them...

```
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 1px;
right: 1px;
bottom: -4px;
height: 2px;
background: #f1f6f9;
border: 1px solid #c5d0d2;
border-top: none;
```

Js Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3my6rhgL/